# How to create the certificate for digitally signing the e-mails?

Tags: email, encryption, digital-signature, thunderbird, electronic-signature

I have a PGP key created, submitted to the pgp.mit.edu and then signed by a friend to join his path(network).

Now I want to start and send an e-mail signed (not encrypted) using the Thunderbird e-mail client, but there it is saying to upload a certificate file which extension is like ***.p12, *.pfx, *.crt** etc.

I created my key using the **Kleopatra** software, how can I create this certificate, if not possible, how can I **sign** my e-mails?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: You need an extension like Enigmail to support PGP from Thunderbird. What you are looking at are options for supporting CMS / S/MIME messages, which is a different protocol taking different cert / key formats.